# L2 Norm of Gaussian Integer

Tags: normed-spaces

I'm writing a Java program that deals with Gaussian Integers. In my program, I have to compute the L2 norm of the GI (Gaussian Integer) and return it as a float.

I've looked around but I cannot seem to find a formula to compute said value.

Is this the correct formula?

```
The l2 norm of a vector is the square root of the sum of the absolute values squared
```

In that case, would the L2 Norm for a+bi be:

```
int sum = abs(a) + abs(b);
int sum = sum*sum;
float norm = sqrt(sum);
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The description is correct, the code isn't. Where it says "sum of the absolute values *squared*", the "squared" applies to "absolute values" and not to "sum". So, correct would be $\sqrt{|a|^2 + |b|^2}$. Note there is no need for the absolute values, $\sqrt{a^2 + b^2}$ is the same.